# Type error on nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

been banging my head on the table over this one.  I have another nested form but this one is driving me crazy.

The error is:

```
TypeError in CompaniesController#create
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
@company = Company.new(company_params)
```

The controller:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'welcome'

  def new
    @company = Company.new
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)

    if @company.save
      flash[:notice] = "New company created successful."
      redirect_to admin_accounts_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Creation failed, please try again"
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:name, :location, :users_attributes => [:email, :password])
  end
end
```

On the new.html.erb:

```
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { company: @company, users_attributes: :users_attributes } %>
```

This code looks exactly like another nested setup I have, but it works :p

I had read that sometimes changing the params from => to just having a semicolon works, but replacing the user_attributes => with a user_attributes: didn't change anything.

EDIT: form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for company, url: companies_path do |f| %>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col p-0 mr-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          Company <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => 'Company name', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :location %>
          <%= f.text_field :location, :placeholder => 'Location', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col p-0">
        <%= f.fields_for users_attributes do |user_f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= user_f.label :email %>
            <%= user_f.text_field :email, :placeholder => 'Your Email Address', class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= user_f.label :password %>
            <%= user_f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password', class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 p-0">
        <%= f.submit "Sign-Up", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you please show me your `_form.html.erb`

Comment: you say type error is in RegistrationsController but you posted CompaniesController

Comment: form added.  Thanks!

Comment: Fixed: put correct _form.html.erb on post

Answer (score 0):

Use `users` instead of `users_attributes` on the form.

Don't forget to define `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users` in model `Company`

```
## new.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { company: @company, users_attributes: :users } %>
```

---

*I wonder why you didn't put `:users` into the `form` directly*

Comment: Changing it to ":users" causes the user portion of the form to not show on the page.  I did it with and without changing it in the controller.

Comment: Quick change, I changed it to the singular usage (:user vs :users) and it shows on the page.  But I still get the type error

Comment: Because “@company” had no users. To do that, in action new, you need to build it: “@company.users.build”